# Multi-value attribute in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-365

I need to specify sales channels to an item and an item could be either one, or multiple, or all of: brick and mortar, online, mass market.

I cannot see how to assign more than one option to an attribute.  Any pointers?

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an attribute of type "MultiSelect Option Set" for your need.

[Read more](https://www.encorebusiness.com/blog/multi-select-option-sets-in-dynamics-365-customer-engagement/)

[image]